# Combining two columns into one column with text added

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

The result I am aiming for is (for all the columns to be calculated)

```
The Number of Invoices Per Date
1 There were a total of 1 invoice(s) on Apr 02, 2012
2 There were a total of 5 invoice(s) on Apr 01, 2012
```

The InvoiceDate Table needs to be formatted but I can't seem to CAST IT at all there's multiple invoice dates on the day which have to be calculated somehow :S

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 107) AS InvoiceDate FROM Invoices
```

above is as far as i've got but it repeats the same date over and over

Comment: `InvoiceDate` is not a table and a table can not be formatted. Instead of using `getdate` you should use your actual datetime column in the table.

Comment: I am trying to format the column into that and count each invoice on said date after its been formatted like I wrote above 1 and 2 are rows the header is the column name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want this:

```
select 
  'There were a total of '
  + cast(count(*) as varchar(10)) 
  + ' invoice(s) on '
  + convert(varchar(12), yourDateCol, 107)
from invoices
group by convert(varchar(12), yourDateCol, 107)
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to group your dates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Quantity, convert(varchar,YourDateFieldName, 107)
FROM Invoices
GROUP BY convert(varchar,YourDateFieldName, 107)
ORDER BT YourDateFieldName
```

Note that GETDATE() (aka CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), in your example, will always return the current timestamp.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was trying to do